# How to boost Kafk's consumer partition reassignment time

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We are using Kafka 1.11
our system challenge is to keep **low latency** on non-down time SLA

We use kafka as our message broker and during our deployments we got latency spikes.

A  - producer to topic X (with 2 partitions)

B,C - consumers of topic X

When shutdown consumer B messages that was sent to B's partition are being delayed(around 1 sec) during re-partition phase till assigned to consumer A

Can you tell how to boost the re-partition phase to minimize this latency when we shut down consumers ?

thanks

Comment: Hey,
I am relatively new to kafka but have you tried looking into: group.min.session.timeout.ms, group.max.session.timeout.ms. 
They are broker configurations that will probably help you detect consumer failures more quickly (at the cost of more heartbeat messages being sent around and handled).
At another glance I see also max.poll.interval.ms (in consumer config) which seems very relevant to your issue: if a consumer doesn't poll for as long as you set this to be, the broker will consider the consumer "dead" and rebalance the partitions.

Comment: But iam shutting my consumer gracefully. The rebalancing process should be right away no?

Comment: I think it should be.
At any rate, I saw this small "article" on this topic, maybe it's useful? https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/partitions-rebalance-kafka-raghunandan-gupta/

Comment: hi @RoyShahaf we have set in the consumer: kafka.heartbeat.interval.ms=500
kafka.session.timeout.ms=1000 and it did the trick. however we are concern what would be the side effects from it? any idea?